# Why use Google Cloud app endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm just starting out with a python written cloud app (appengine app?). So far I have seen these methods for communicating with my cloud app:

1. HTTP-requests
2. Cloud endpoints

Is there anything I can do with endpoints that I can't do with HTTP-requests? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew Is from the Google I/O '13. It covers the usage of endpoints fairly well.